# Firebase cloud function on non google server

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

The cloud function in firebase needs you to enable the billing plan.
Can I use cloud functions on my own Nodejs server and access the events by installing `npm install firebase-functions` without enable cloud functions on firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only use the Firebase Functions Emulator to test your functions locally (you cannot deploy to Firebase unless you enable billing). Self-hosting a server is different and using *server-less* Cloud functions and may not be as easy to scale like Cloud functions do.

The events (like Firestore triggers) that you are referring to can be used to trigger Cloud functions only. If you host your server on your server then it'll be best to route all the operations through it. For example, if you wanted to trigger a function when a new document is added to Firestore, instead of creating the document directly from client make a request to your server and add the document using Admin SDK and process anything else at the same time.

Comment: I need to trigger notification when a new doc added to firestore. Is there anyway to listen event on my own nodejs server?

Comment: @J.MARS no. The only way is to update the document via your server. So whenever any user tries to add a doc you can do both the tasks - adding a new doc and processing whatever the triggered function would have done.